# How is `results` in this being evaluated?

Tags: javascript

Could someone help me understand how this is working?

I understand how callbacks work but I was watching a tutorial video and came across this snippet of code:

```
function addAndHandle(n1, n2, cb) {
    const result = n1 + n2;
    cb(result);
}

addAndHandle(10, 20, function (results) {
    console.log(results);
});
```

My question in this is, how is `results` being calculated here in the callback. In the function declaration, the `result` is being passed into the callback which makes sense because the sum is being stored in `result`. However, later I am using `results` so how is that showing the sum of `10` and `20` or whatever `n1` and `n2` are?

Comment: `result` is the argument being passed in to the function you pass into `addAndHandle`.. if you edited `addAndHandle` to say `cb('e')`, you would end up logging `e` to the console

Comment: There are two independent variables names `results`. Don't confuse them.

Comment: im calling them the same thing because `result` **IS** what is passed into `cb` and called `results`

Answer (score 1):

You call the function with the three parameters.

The function adds n1 and n2 and saves the result in a variable

Then you pass that Varbiable to the function.

Maybe naming the parameter different helps

```
function addAndHandle(n1, n2, cb) {
    const result = n1 + n2;
    cb(result);
}

addAndHandle(10, 20, function (p_nResult) {
    console.log(p_nResult);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe writing it like this will help you understand:

```
function addAndHandle(n1, n2, cb) {
    const result = n1 + n2;
    cb(result);
}

function foo(results) {
    console.log(results);
}

addAndHandle(10, 20,foo);
```

Inside addAndHanle function you call cb - you are calling foo, result is equal to 30.
It's the same as calling foo with 30:

```
foo(30)
```

So - results is calculated with `const result = n1 + n2`, this gives you a value that you pass on to foo.

In your example you are using anonymous function as callabck, but the logic is the same.
All i did was to extract your cb into a separate function to simplify it.

Comment: In the function declaration, the `result` is a const which has the scope of a function. And the result of `n1 + n2` is stored. If I pass in `10` and `20` for `n1` and `n2`, that still means that `result` const is staying the same and only n1 and n2 are being updated. So how is the callback function able to show the sum despite the name of the variable being different?

Comment: *So how is the callback function able to show the sum despite the name of the variable being different* - when you write `function test(args){}` you can call it with any name that you want `test(4) / test("ss)`. The variable name is different BUT the important thing is that you are sending a value to the function. so even tho you have different names the function is able to figure out the value of your argument.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused since `result` and `results` are the same in this example. Your `result` is passed into your callback
(`function (results) {console.log(results);}`) as `results`

These are the values your working with at the end

```
function addAndHandle(n1 /* 10 */, n2 /* 20 */, cb /* function (results) {console.log(results);} */) {
    const result = n1 + n2; /* 30 */
    // This is just calling your callback function from below with the value of result eg. 30
    cb(result /* 30 */);

    // in case your familiar with IIF
    (function (results) {console.log(results);})(result)


addAndHandle(10, 20, function (results /* 30 */) {
    console.log(results /* 30 */);
});
```